# Wallpaper Identification: Where can I find a better version of this?

Tags: ipad

(Please forgive me + nuke from orbit of these kinds of questions aren't allowed here. Don't know where else to ask.)

I'm trying to find a higher-res version of this specific wallpaper:
[image: iPhone Wallpaper]

The site where I got the iPhone version did not deal with iPad wallpapers, so I didn't have an option there. Nor did it list an author for me to track down. I've tried Google image search for similar images and just plain browsing a ton of other sites, but I can't find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's actually Tiger's (Mac OSX 10.4) default wallpaper.

I found one easily on Google searching `Tiger default wallpaper` : http://www.journaldulapin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Aqua-Blue-10.4.jpg

It might just need a little rotation :)

Comment: wow, what a keen eye :)

Comment: This is why I asked here. Awesome, thanks! :)